# How can I prove that the sequence converges to $\log(2)$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, proof, continued-fractions

There are two rational sequences.

One of them describes convergents of the continued fraction for $\log(2)$.
Its Mathematica code is as follows:

```
Convergents[ContinuedFraction[Log[2], 10]]
(* {0, 1, 2/3, 7/10, 9/13, ...} *)
```

Obviously by the definition, this sequence converges to $\log(2)$.

Another sequence is described by the following Mathematica code:

```
Simplify[
 Table[Log[2]+(-1)^n Integrate[(1-x)^(4n+2)/(1+x^2), {x, 0, 1}]/4^n, {n, 0, 10}]]
(* {1, 79/120, 14087/20160, 3990557/5765760, 217474889/313657344, ...} *)
```

It is alleged that this sequence converges to $\log(2)$ as well.

Using Mathematica, how can I prove that the second sequence indeed converges to $\log(2)$?

FYI Maple is correctly handling the limit of this integral.

limit(int((1-x)^(2+4*n)/(1+x^2), x=0..1), n=infinity);

limit(2^(-4*n-3)*MeijerG([[1/2], [2*n+2, 2*n+3/2]],[[1/2, 1/2, 0], []],1)*GAMMA (4*n+3),n = infinity)

Value to be looked up: 0

Comment: I don't see a direct way to do this. The integration result is a hypergeometric, in a form that `Limit` will not be able to handle.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau - could you submit to Mathematica developers a feature request to implement functionality which would use logic provided by Daniel Huber in his answer?

Comment: Why don't you just show the integral goes to zero? `Log[2]` seems a red herring.

Comment: @Michael E2 - see OEIS  A363515 and A363516.

Comment: What "functionality" would this be? What would be the input? And the corresponding output? (To address the question actually asked, no, I'm not making a suggestion about this. As my own questions indicate, I'd have no idea what to suggest even if I was so inclined.)

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Dear Daniel, it should work under the LIMIT input framework. The output should tell that the expression converges to Log[2]. You don't need to tell your developers how to implement it - they should figure it out... Just point them to the answers provided by Daniel Huber and Michael E2.

Comment: I am the developer in this case. And the methods they show will not work here. One problem being the integral evaluates and so is not available for analysis when `Limit` is reached. (I did check this, by the way.)

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau FYI Maple is correctly handling the limit of this integral.                                       limit(int((1-x)^(2+4*n)/(1+x^2), x=0..1), n=infinity);                                                    limit(2^(-4*n-3)*MeijerG([[1/2], [2*n+2, 2*n+3/2]],[[1/2, 1/2, 0], []],1)*GAMMA
(4*n+3),n = infinity)
Value to be looked up: 0

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Have you looked at Maple solution which I quoted in the previous message?

Comment: Maple appears to have a series expansion worked out for MeijerG in cases of parameter repeats in this case.

Answer (score 6):

Consider your expression:

```
  Log[2]+(-1)^n Integrate[(1-x)^(4n+2)/(1+x^2), {x, 0, 1}]/4^n
```

To show that this converges to Log[2] it suffice to show that the second part:

```
(-1)^n Integrate[(1 - x)^(4 n + 2)/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, 1}]/4^n
```

converges to zero. This is true if:

```
Integrate[(1 - x)^(4 n + 2)/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, 1}]
```

does. Note, that the integrand is positive. Therefore an upper bond is:

```
Integrate[(1 - x)^(4 n + 2), {x, 0, 1}]

1/(3+4n)
```

and this converges to zero as n->Infinity.

Comment: FYI Maple is correctly handling the limit of this integral. limit(int((1-x)^(2+4*n)/(1+x^2), x=0..1), n=infinity); limit(2^(-4*n-3)*MeijerG([[1/2], [2*n+2, 2*n+3/2]],[[1/2, 1/2, 0], []],1)*GAMMA (4*n+3),n = infinity) Value to be looked up: 0

Answer (score 6):

Kinda like Daniel's, human reasoning + computational assistance, but along a different track:

The integrand is positive so the integral is a positive function of `n`:

```
(1 - x)^(4 n + 2)/(1 + x^2) > 0 // 
 FullSimplify[#, n > 1 && 0 < x < 1] &

(*  True *)
```

Applying Leibniz's rule, the derivative (w.r.t. `n`) of the integrand, and therefore the derivative of the integral is negative:

```
D[(1 - x)^(4 n + 2)/(1 + x^2), n] < 0 // 
 FullSimplify[#, n > 1 && 0 < x < 1] &

(*  True  *)
```

Therefore the integral is a decreasing positive function of `n`,
hence bounded. Therefore the integral divided by `4^n` goes to zero.

[I've never figured out how to get Mathematica to make deductions about integrals based on integrands the way this argument and Daniel's do.]

Comment: FYI Maple is correctly handling the limit of this integral.                                          limit(int((1-x)^(2+4*n)/(1+x^2), x=0..1), n=infinity);                                          limit(2^(-4*n-3)*MeijerG([[1/2], [2*n+2, 2*n+3/2]],[[1/2, 1/2, 0], []],1)*GAMMA (4*n+3),n = infinity) Value to be looked up: 0

Comment: @Alex Since we're talking about software and not mathematics, isn't more correct to say that Maple finds the limit of the result of `int()`? Or is it the case that Maple cannot find the integral?

Comment: Without nitpicking on the words I used,  one  could clearly see that as you said it: "Maple finds the limit of the result of int()". :-)

Comment: @Alex It wasn't clear to me. I don't now how Maple works. In an earlier comment, you were saying Mathematica should analyze `Limit[Integrate[..]..]` in terms of the unevaluated `Integrate[]` as Daniel H. and I did. I thought maybe you were telling me that Maple does this sort of thing. If the Meijer G expression is the result of `int()`, it seems different than Mathematica's result, no? I wonder which is correct? Or maybe they're equivalent? Mma seems to hate that Meijer G expression, if I transcribed it right.

Comment: Maple clearly indicated that the limit is 0 and I trust this result. I am leaving it to others, particularly to Daniel Lichtblau, who per his words does development work for Mathematica to research why Maple is capable to evaluate the limit correctly and Mathematica is not...

Comment: The Meijer G-function is a special function in mathematics that generalizes several other functions, such as the hypergeometric function.
It is denoted by G(aᵢ, bⱼ, z), where aᵢ and bⱼ are sequences of complex numbers and z is the input variable.
The Meijer G-function has applications in various areas of mathematics, including complex analysis, number theory, and physics. It arises in the solutions of differential equations, integral transforms, and the evaluation of certain types of integrals.

Comment: `Limit[1/n, n -> Infinity]` gives the correct limit for this problem, too, by the way. OTOH, I can numerically verify Mathematica's integral, but Mathematica cannot numerically evaluate Maple's Meijer G formula, so I cannot coment on its in/accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Computing polynomials (mod 1+x²) is equivalent to replacing x = i = sqrt(-1).

So, (1-x)^(4n) == (1-i)^(4n) = (-4)^n (mod 1+x²), therefore

f(x) := (-1/4)^n * (1-x)^(4n+4) / (1+x²) = -4 / (1+x²) + polynomial

g(x) := (-1/4)^n * (1-x)^(4n+2) / (1+x²) = -2x / (1+x²) + polynomial.

If polynomial = $\sum a_k x^k$ (depending on n), then primitives are

$F(x) = -4 \arctan x + P(x)~$ resp. $~G(x) = -\log(1+x^2) + P(x)$,

with $~P(x) = P_n(x) = \sum \frac{a_k}{k+1}\,x^{k+1}$.

Therefore $~\int_0^1 f = F(1) = P(1) - \pi~$ and $~\int_0^1 g = G(1) = P(1) - \log2$.

Since the integrand and integrals are less than $1/4^n$ in absolute value, the whole thing (F(1) resp. G(1)) tends to zero, whence $P(1) = P_n(1)$
(which for g is exactly your second sequence) tends to $\pi$ or $\log 2$ as $n\to\infty$.